# when to use mySQL vs pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm starting a data analytics project where I will need to store hundreds of business metrics for hundreds of stocks with daily frequency over 10 years, possibly under separate tables. My question is : what are the pros and cons of using mySQL / other RDBMS to aggregate, store and manage the data when it's downloaded vs. just using pandas and hdf5 file formats?

Comment: This really calls for an opinion, which is often frowned upon here, however personally I'm a fan of MySQL. It can handle large amounts of data, is well supported around the globe and very mature. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: Thanks. You're right about opinions: what I'm hoping for is more figures with benchmarks (http://wesmckinney.com/blog/high-performance-database-joins-with-pandas-dataframe-more-benchmarks/) as to what is faster / can handle larger amounts of data / can better manage relationshps, etc.

Comment: General benchmarks are a load of garbage. The only benchmark that matters is how the database performs on the hardware you have available using the data you're intending to store in it. A Ferrari is a really fast car on a race-track, but it's not very fast in stop and go traffic, and it's considerably slower than a minivan at getting groceries from the store if you need to make multiple trips because of a lack of trunk space. Your needs are extremely relevant here.

Comment: Can you then roughly map needs to usage? In what case is pandas dataframe the way to go vs mySQL (pros and cons)? When should I use the ferrari vs the minivan?